# Resizing an elements when window is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize

Im having a little trouble with how I would tackle this problem. I am working on a project that I need to be able to create areas or selections on an image. The only problem I am having is how I would be able to have the created elements re-size when the window dimensions are changed.
http://pastebin.com/qNuUm3U4

Is my basic coding already, there is a lot of stuff being logged just to help me throughout the process, but the things I were needing to be re-sized with a window re-size were the divs being created in the tag function. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you want to do? The areas should be only on images, right?

Comment: I want the created areas(Gray boxes) to resize if the window size is changed, currently they just disappear because they're set with window co-ordinates(Top,left,bottom and right in the css) but I have no real idea how to accurately do that

Comment: Use css width & height properties in terms of %
like .abc{
width=20%;
height=20%;
}

Comment: For the image or the created areas?

Comment: Trying with % width helps but it ignores the co-ordinates of the actual area selected when used on the selected areas

Comment: Could you possibly create a jsfiddle? Then it would be easier to test this out

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y8doo3fy/
I think this should work. With this, I would like it so when the output window is resized, the area that you created stays the same size and location it was initially placed